# Can't seem to update a Multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a function which calculates weights for my thesis and although it calculates all the weights perfectly using pypfopt, the result (which is a dictionary called "weights") can't be inserted in my MultiIndex df which I wanted to save. in a parquet file.

To make it work, I used the code:

(1)

```
# Store results in dataframe
for key in weights.keys(): 
   results_df.loc[date, (df_name, cov, freq, w, parameter, beta, key)] = weights[key]
```

The first attempt was:

(2)

```
# Store results in dataframe
results_df.loc[date, (df_name, cov, freq, w, parameter, beta)] = weights
```

Which doesn't work. Now, is there a cleaner way to do the same as (1) without the need for a loop?

I first tried:

```
results_df.loc[date, (df_name, cov, freq, w, parameter, beta)] = weights
```

It only worked, however, when I tried:

```
for key in weights.keys(): 
   results_df.loc[date, (df_name, cov, freq, w, parameter, beta, key)] = weights[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume your `weights` dictionary is string key and scalar value, you can create a multiindex weights dataframe with `pd.concat` then concat it to your original dataframe

```py
weights = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
out = pd.concat([df, pd.concat({(df_name, cov, freq, w, parameter, beta): pd.DataFrame([weights], index=[date])}, axis=1)], axis=1)
```